# Accessing the app name from inside a rails template when generating rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

I'm messing around with rails 2.3 templates and want to be able to use the app name as a variable inside my template, so when I use...

    `rails appname -m path/to/template.rb`


...I want to be able to access appname inside template.rb.  Anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.  Mike Woodhouse, you were so close.  Turns out, all you need to do to access the appname from inside your rails template is...

```
@root.split('/').last
```

The @root variable is the first thing created when initializing templates and is available inside your rails templates.  RAILS_ROOT does not work.

Answer (score 16):

I was looking for an answer to this question. unfortunately the answer above (@root) doesn't seem to work in Rails 3.

Here's the variables you can access in Rails 3 app templates (even easier):

```
@app_name
@app_path
```

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 3, use the `app_name` attribute.

See the documentation for the [Rails::Generators::AppGenerator](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/AppGenerator.html).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem, none of the variables listed above were available to me in Rails 4. I found that `@name` was available while running

```
rails plugin new engines/dummy -m my_template.rb
```

There are other useful variables available from within the template. You can see for yourself and play around by utilizing `pry`. Inside my template I added

```
require 'pry'; binding.pry
```

and then ran `ls` to show a list of available instance variables

```
ls -i
instance variables:
    @_initializer            @app_path  @behavior   @destination_stack  @extra_entries  @name           @output_buffer   @shell
    @_invocations            @args      @builder    @dummy_path         @gem_filter     @options        @rails_template  @source_paths
    @after_bundle_callbacks  @author    @camelized  @email              @in_group       @original_name  @shebang
```

Comment: This answer is time proof, should be the top one

Answer (score 4):

There's probably a more straightforward way, but this seems to work:

```
RAILS_ROOT.split('/').last
```

EDIT: Bleah - this got voted down once, and the voter was right. If I'd read the question more carefully, I'd have noticed the 2.3 and template.rb elements. Apologies.

I suspect that RAILS_ROOT won't have been created at the point that you need the app name. Looking at `ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\rails-2.2.2\bin\rails`, however, almost the first thing that happens is this:

```
app_path = ARGV.first
```

It's used at the end of the script to allow a chdir and freeze to be done if needed - I didn't know I could insta-freeze at creation, so I learned something new at least. `ARGV` then gets used here:

```
Rails::Generator::Scripts::Generate.new.run(ARGV, :generator => 'app')
```

which quickly gets us to the place where ARGV is really handled:

```
rails-2.3.1\lib\rails_generator\scripts.rb
```

where I see

```
Rails::Generator::Base.instance(options[:generator], args, options).command(options[:command]).invoke!
```

Somewhere below here is probably where the templating gets handled. I'm afraid I'm at a very early stage with 2.3 and templating is an area that I haven't looked at yet.

Does that help any better than my first effort?

Answer (score 1):

RAILS_ROOT will give you the absolute path to your root directory. Your app name will be the portion of the string after the final '/' which you can grab in any number of ways.

EDIT: Not quite enough to get the job done. Mike and Dan iron it out below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the preferred way now is to call Rails.root and no longer RAILS_ROOT. Apparently someone on planet rails has an aversion to uppercase or some similar important reason. As of 2.3.5 they both appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error

```
`template': undefined local variable or method `app_name'
```

ruby 1.9.2p290, rails 3.2.11, thor 0.18.0, Windows

but with rails 2.3 generator:

```
class DynanavGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
```

(can't be sure whether this error happened under rails 3.0.9 or earlier)
changed class definition to be:

```
class DynanavGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
```

which then gave:

> No value provided for required arguments 'name'

I then added a 'name' ("something" below):

```
rails generate dynanav something --force
```

which gave the original error, so I then added:

```
def app_name
  @name.titleize
end
```

to the class and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 4 (maybe earlier versions?), use Rails.application.class to get the application name. For example, if your app is named Fizzbuzz, here are a few ways you might access it:

```
rails(development)> Rails.application.class
=> Fizzbuzz::Application
rails(development)> Rails.application.class.name
=> "Fizzbuzz::Application"
rails(development)> Rails.application.class.parent
=> Fizzbuzz
rails(development)> Rails.application.class.parent.to_s
=> "Fizzbuzz"
```